# how to split dataframe vertically, having N columns in each resulting DF

Tags: python, pandas, date, split

I have the following dataframe:

> ```
> Date     2017-12-05 2017-12-06 2017-12-15 2017-12-19 2017-12-20  2017-12-21   ....
> time                                                                         
> 00:00:00      19.94      21.19      21.88      20.76      21.26      21.26   
> 00:15:00      20.29      21.07      21.71      21.79      21.95      21.52   
> 00:30:00      21.03      21.25      21.80      22.15      22.26      21.62   
> 00:45:00      22.20      21.56      22.77      22.20      22.33      21.91   
> 01:00:00      23.25      22.15      23.71      22.31      22.69      21.99   
> 01:15:00      23.78      23.33      24.53      22.29      22.82      22.58
> ```

Columns are dates, and I want to split the dataframe by every 3 date columns. How can I do this?

Illustration of the final result with one of the resultant dataframes following the split:

```
Date      2017-12-05 2017-12-06 2017-12-15 2
     time                                                                         
     00:00:00      19.94      21.19      21.88      
     00:15:00      20.29      21.07      21.71      
     00:30:00      21.03      21.25      21.80      
     00:45:00      22.20      21.56      22.77      
     01:00:00      23.25      22.15      23.71      
     01:15:00      23.78      23.33      24.53
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [np.split(..., axis=1)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
In [157]: N = 3

In [158]: dfs = np.split(df, np.arange(N, len(df.columns), N), axis=1)

In [159]: dfs[0]
Out[159]:
          2017-12-05  2017-12-06  2017-12-15
00:00:00       19.94       21.19       21.88
00:15:00       20.29       21.07       21.71
00:30:00       21.03       21.25       21.80
00:45:00       22.20       21.56       22.77
01:00:00       23.25       22.15       23.71
01:15:00       23.78       23.33       24.53

In [160]: dfs[1]
Out[160]:
          2017-12-19  2017-12-20  2017-12-21
00:00:00       20.76       21.26       21.26
00:15:00       21.79       21.95       21.52
00:30:00       22.15       22.26       21.62
00:45:00       22.20       22.33       21.91
01:00:00       22.31       22.69       21.99
01:15:00       22.29       22.82       22.58
```

Comment: this gives an error in case the no. of columns isn't a multiple of the number you split by

Comment: I can't figure out from the docs how to use this indices_or_sections parameter. In any event, one can truncate the dataframe so that it can be split with np.split and then (if wanted/needed) consider the rest.

Comment: Also I notice now that the title doesn't make sense: "split horizontally", and then by columns !?

Comment: @user2314737, oh my bad. [Now I see](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293520/split-horizontally-or-vertically-which-one-is-which) ... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
ddf=[]
for i in range(len(df.columns)/3):
    ddf.append(df[df.columns[3*i:3*i+3]])
```

to generate a list `df` of dataframes, each with 3 columns.
Add the rest (with less than 3 columns):

```
ddf.append(df[df.columns[3*(i+1):]])
```